# Load classes from referenced project

Tags: quarkus

I have a Quarkus Maven project, which has dependencies to multiple other projects.

Is it possible to load all classes (respectively class names) which are defined within my own project and the referenced ones?

I tried to get this information from the *jandex.idx* file in my project, but here only the classes, which are defined within the project itself are available.

Example / Test implementation

```
public String listClasses() {
    final var indexStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/META-INF/jandex.idx");
    final var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    if (indexStream != null) {
        IndexReader reader = new IndexReader(indexStream);
        try {
            Index index = reader.read();
            // index.getKnownClasses() contains only the classes of my project
            index.getKnownClasses().stream().forEach(c -> stringBuilder.append(c.name() + " || "));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

When using a Quarkus extension, the *CombinedIndexBuildItem* has all this information.

Example:

```
@BuildStep
void printBOs(CombinedIndexBuildItem combinedIndexBuildItem,
              BuildProducer<AdditionalBeanBuildItem> additionalBeans) {

    final var classInfos = combinedIndexBuildItem.getIndex().getKnownClasses();
    
    // classInfos contains all classes which are defined
}
```

But the usage of the Quarkus extension is not an option, as it requires to have a completely runnable "application" (in my understanding). So the *build* step of the quarkus-maven-plugin checks the application.properties, whether all injected interfaces have an implementation, etc.

As a hint: This is a simplified constellation. We have hundreds of Maven projects and every project/module needs to know its own classes and the ones from the referenced projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have thought it too complicated.
The solution is simply to load all jandex.idx files and then read the classes with IndexReader. So I use *getResources* instead of *getResourceAsStream*.

Example

```
final var classes = new StringJoiner(" || ");

try {
    final var resources = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResources("/META-INF/jandex.idx");
    while (resources.hasMoreElements()) {
        final var url = resources.nextElement();
        final var reader = new IndexReader(url.openStream());
        Index index = reader.read();

        index.getKnownClasses().stream()
                .filter(classInfo -> classInfo.name().toString().startsWith("my.package."))
                .forEach(classInfo -> classes.add(classInfo.name().toString()));

    }

}
catch (IOException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```